# How to call python function from javascript in django?

Tags: python, django, web

I'm making a Cubing Timer app. I have a django app which loads python function that generates a scramble from file in `views.py`. I have a JS file that runs timer by clicking Space bar. I want to generate new scramble everytime timer stops.

How to do that?

Here is my `views.py` file:

```
from .scramble_generator import *

def home(request):
    s = scramble_replace(scramble_gen())
    scramble = sprint(valid(s))
    return render(request, 'timer/index.html', {'scramble':scramble})
```

`main.js`:

```
let state = 'stopped';

const transitions = {
  waiting: state => ResetTimer(),
  started: state => StartTimer(),
  stopped: state => PauseTimer(),
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeState);
document.addEventListener('keyup', changeState);

function changeState({code, repeat, type: action}){

  if(code !== 'Space' || repeat){
    return;
  }

  // this allows to have more event types and states in the future without cluttering
  const actions = {
    keydown: () => state === 'stopped' ? 'waiting' : 'stopped',
    keyup: () => state === 'stopped' ? state : 'started',
  };

  // determine the next state 
  const next = actions[action]();
  // if the next state is different, commit it to the current and execute transition
  next === state || transitions[state = next](state);

}
```

Comment: Please can you explain why you need to call a python function that is triggered by javascript? Elaborate a little bit the context of your question please. E.g. What are you trying to do? How have you you tried to do it already?

Comment: You load JS files in your HTML template.  Example: ``<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'your_app/scripts/your_js_file.js' %}"></script>`.  To give a better response I'd need to see more of your code.  I'm not understaning perhaps what you mean by call a python function from javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by making a endpoint in Django and then making a http request from javascript when you need to call the function.

Here is how you can do it

Create a new URL pattern in your Django urls.py file to map to the API endpoint:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [path('api/function/', views.home, name='get_function'),# other URL patterns...]
```

Once you add this you can call it from javascript like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/api/function/');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var functionName = response.function;
        // Now you can use the functionName as desired in your JavaScript code
        // For example, you can call the function
        window[functionName]();
    } else {
        console.log('Error:', xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```